# C++ code printing strange values

Tags: c++

i am having a very silly but strange problem. When i am trying to compile and run the following code my compiler is printing "ggl" but i think it shouldn't. It is strange that after doing so much programming i am stuck here. What exactly is the problem? Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance !!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t=8;
    if(1<t<5){
        cout<<"ggl";
    }
    //cout<<aa;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it does

```
 if(1<t<5)
```

You would have to say

```
 if (1 < t && t < 5)
```

The first version says

```
if ((1 < t) < 5)
```

Which evaluates to

```
if (true < 5)
if (1 < 5)
```

Which is always true.

Comment: We appear to be typing the same things at the same time. I'll +1 yours anyway.

Comment: Thanks Cyber for the quick response !! Is this (1<t<5) way of writing comparison statements used anywhere in programming ? Because i still can't believe that that is not the right way. I think i have been using it earlier. Thanks !!

Comment: @varunkr In general, most languages have the behavior that you just saw for the reason I described. One exception that comes to mind is `Python` that allows the syntax you originally wrote.

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` condition effectively says `if ((1 < t) < 5)`, which is always true, because `(1 < t)` is either 1 or 0 (`1 < 8` evaluates to 1).

Since chained comparisons do not (usually) work in C++, you'll need to check the condition differently:

```
if (1 < t && t < 5) {
    cout << "ggl";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
if(1<t<5)
```

does not do what you think it does. It does not determine whether `t` is between 1 and 5. You want

```
if ((1<t) && (t<5))
```

What it actually does is take the value `(1<t)` (which will 1 if `1<t` and 0 otherwise), then see if that value is less than 5, which it always will be.